# `Flask` cache is ignoring parameters and returning same response

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

Been playing with caching in Flask for a few hours, but I keep running into an issue that I cannot seem to resolve. I have a route that takes any number of parameters, none of which are defined, (`i.e. def get_data()`). The parameters are then passed through to a utility function to check if they are valid columns in a SQL table, and if they are, they are then piped to another function that executes a `SELECT` statement with those parameters.

I have a caching configuration set-up with flask:

```
caching_config = {
    "DEBUG": True,          
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 60
}
```

And I have the decorator set-up as so:

```
@app.route("/data", methods = ["POST"])
@cache.cached()
def data():
   ...
```

The caching *works*, but not in the intended way. Perhaps because there are no parameters specified to the API, but when called a second time to initiate the cache, the API will returned the cached data *regardless* of what parameters are passed through.

For example, say user A requests: `http://url.com/data` with `fruit` set to Apple. The query works as intended, and if user A requests it again within 60 seconds, that cached data is returned. But say that user A, instead, requests the same endpoint with `fruit` set to Orange -- within 60 seconds of the first (Apple) request. Now instead of returning the proper data requested, the API will still return the `Apple` request **despite** new parameters being introduced. This occurs until the cache timeout is reached, when the cycle will begin again.

Is this a product of not having parameters defined? It would be a real pain to do so, with the idea that the user can filter on any of the available columns, and listing each possible column for every parameter seems backwards. Or is there some hidden variable that I should be setting somewhere in my caching initialization?

Still new to this, and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Provide `query_string` keyword to the cached decorator.

```
@app.route("/data", methods = ["POST"])
@cache.cached(query_string=True)
def data():
   ...
```

A ***cache_key*** will be created by hashing the query string parameters in order.

If you add more parameters in the future than just `fruit`, each unique set of parameters for a url will have its own ***cache_key***. Thus, the order of parameters does not matter.